# Does java source code has test cases?

Tags: java

I was not able to find any test cases for java source code. I thought having a look at test cases for some of the advanced java classes would be a great way to learn about the class and also would be a great insight on writing test cases. Are there any test cases that test Java source code ?

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/test - for example, tests relating to `BufferedInputStream`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/test/java/io/BufferedInputStream. *Note*: this is the openJDK source

Comment: Your Java source code will have test cases if you write them.

Comment: @TylerSebastian I browsed around OpenJDK before posting this, but I was not able to find any test cases. I got lost in that site structure. Thanks for the link, this is what I exactly needed. However are there any other test cases apart from those in OpenJDK. I am looking at ThreadLocal.java class and it doesn't seem exhaustive.

Comment: @guptat59 the unicorn of the QA world is an exhaustive test suite. There are always going to be coverage holes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the OpenJDK source code [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8), and browse around. They're using a Mercurial repo, so you can click on `jdk`, then `browse` on the left bar, then `test` to start digging through the test code.

It's worth noting that this isn't *necessarily* the most modern way of testing java code - usually, you'd want to use a library like JUnit to manage your tests. OpenJDK is simply using a makefile, to ensure that there are no dependencies when building Java.